# Line numbers for displayed maths inside boxed minipage

Tags: minipage, line-numbering, lineno

I need to add line numbers to things like the following, probably inside the box and at the right-hand side, with numbers on all the lines, including the maths. I see that there is a package called lineno for adding line numbers, and that it has commands to cope with displayed maths and with minipages, but I need both together and I have not managed to get anything to work. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lineno}

\begin{document}
\fboxsep=12pt
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[c]{28.5pc}
\raggedright
\textbf{Solution}
\begin{enumerate}
\item [(a)]
In \((U_9,\times_9)\) we have:
 \[\begin{aligned}
 &2^2 = 4,\\
 &2^3 = 8,\\
 &2^4 = 2\times_9 8= 7,\\
 &2^5 = 2\times_9 7=5,\\
 &2^6 = 2\times_9 5=1.
 \end{aligned}\]
Thus \(\langle 2 \rangle = \{1,2,4,8,7,5\} = U_9\), 
so \(U_9\) is cyclic and 2 is a generator for~\(U_9\).
\item [(b)]
An isomorphism from \((U_9, \times_9)\) to~\( (\mathbb{Z}_6, +_6)\) is as follows.
 \[\begin{aligned} 
 \phi : \:(U_9,\times_9) & \longrightarrow (\mathbb{Z}_6,+_6)\\
 1 & \longmapsto 0\\
 2 & \longmapsto 1\\
 4 & \longmapsto 2\\
 8 & \longmapsto 3\\
 7 & \longmapsto 4\\
 5 & \longmapsto 5.
 \end{aligned}\] 
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

[image: The output of the code.]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!